# css, reverse transition on different class

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

When the width of the element grows I want my animation to start off by shrinking and stopping instantly when it's big. When it's big I want to start instantly and shrink a little further than the end state. When the element enters the page however, the element starts below the page until it's in the center.

I started with `cubic-bezier(0.4, -0.5, 1,1);` as timing function to have to grow effect. However I'm failing to meet the conditions I stated above.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3dnx6s6/2/)

```js
let big = document.getElementById('big')
let cube  = document.getElementById('cube')

big.addEventListener("click", t)

function t (){
 let isBig = cube.classList.contains('big')
 if(isBig){
  cube.classList.remove("big")
  cube.classList.add("small")
 big.innerText =  "Make big" 
 }
 else{
   cube.classList.remove("small")
   cube.classList.add("big")
  big.innerText =  "Make small" 
 }
}
```

```css
.ctnr{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.cube{
  height: 10rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  transition: width 1s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, -0.5, 1,1); 
  animation-name: incomming;
  animation-duration: 0.7s;
}

.big{
  width: 20rem;
  background:orange;
}
.small{
  width: 10rem;
  background:deeppink;

}

@keyframes incomming {
  0%{
    margin-bottom:-100%;
  }
  100%{
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="big">
Make big
</button>
<div class="ctnr">
  <div id="cube" class="cube small">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your animation description is a bit unclear (at least for me) but from what I understand it should be either:

```css
.cube{
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.84,0,.63,1.42);
}
.big.cube {
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.35,-.35,.48,.84);  
}
```

```js
let big = document.getElementById('big')
let cube  = document.getElementById('cube')

big.addEventListener("click", t)

function t (){
 let isBig = cube.classList.contains('big')
 if(isBig){
  cube.classList.remove("big")
  cube.classList.add("small")
 big.innerText =  "Make big" 
 }
 else{
   cube.classList.remove("small")
   cube.classList.add("big")
  big.innerText =  "Make small" 
 }
}
```

```css
.ctnr{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.cube{
  height: 10rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  transition: width 1s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.84,0,.63,1.42);
  animation-name: incomming;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

.big{
  width: 20rem;
  background:orange;
}
.big.cube {
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.35,-.35,.48,.84);  
}
.small{
  width: 10rem;
  background:deeppink;
}

@keyframes incomming {
  0%{
    margin-bottom:-100%;
  }
  100%{
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="big">
Make big
</button>
<div class="ctnr">
  <div id="cube" class="cube small">

  </div>
</div>
```

... or:

```css
.cube{
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.84,0,.63,1.42);
}
.big.cube {
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.35,-.35,.84,.48);  
}
```

```js
let big = document.getElementById('big')
let cube  = document.getElementById('cube')

big.addEventListener("click", t)

function t (){
 let isBig = cube.classList.contains('big')
 if(isBig){
  cube.classList.remove("big")
  cube.classList.add("small")
 big.innerText =  "Make big" 
 }
 else{
   cube.classList.remove("small")
   cube.classList.add("big")
  big.innerText =  "Make small" 
 }
}
```

```css
.ctnr{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.cube{
  height: 10rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  transition: width 1s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.84, 0, 0.63, 1.42);
  animation-name: incomming;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

.big{
  width: 20rem;
  background:orange;
}
.big.cube {
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.35,-.35,.84,.48);  
}
.small{
  width: 10rem;
  background:deeppink;
}

@keyframes incomming {
  0%{
    margin-bottom:-100%;
  }
  100%{
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="big">
Make big
</button>
<div class="ctnr">
  <div id="cube" class="cube small">

  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if I got it right or if you want it modified. If none is correct, perhaps you could use some of these terms so I could understand it better:

- `ease-in`: gradual acceleration
- `ease-out`: gradual deceleration
- `ease-in-out` (a.k.a. easy ease): both of the above (slow start and end with fast middle)
- `spring` (a.k.a. anticipation/overlap) to go over the value in an elastic way in order to start in opposite direction (anticipation) or to stop from the opposite direction (overlap)

**Note:** Probably going through [`the 12 animation principles`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12_basic_principles_of_animation) defined by Disney might help you better describe the effect you are after.

**Tooling:** I needed to make sense of `cubic-bezier()` when there were no proper tools for it, at least from my perspective and compared to now. That drastically changed when Chrome added a real time visualization tool to their developer console. Open the console on any element in Chrome and click the tiny square symbol next to the `cubic-bezier()` set on that element. And drag the dot segments around to change the bezier function.
Congratulations! You're now officially a `cubic-bezier()` expert.

Comment: Seems like the second one is what I want. It visually look like it but the values seem weird. But I'm pleased with the result so it will do. Thanks for the link as well, very interesting !

Comment: @Ced, I added a ***tooling*** note to my answer to help you make more sense of `cubic-bezier()`. Cheers!